# SonarQube MSBuild runner and scm root

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

good day
today i was setup sonarqube with ms build runner and mercurial scm provider
i have next structure of repository (schematic):

```
<ROOT>
-.hg
-src
----prj.infrastructure 
----prj.domain
----prj.application
----prj.sln
```

and i used next command for run analysis:

```
"%env.SonarMsBuildRunner%\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner" begin /n:prj /k:prj /v:1.0
"%env.MsBuildLocation%\msbuild" src\prj.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
"%env.SonarMsBuildRunner%\msbuild.sonarqube.runner" end
```

all analysis are work well, but scm not work (i see message like " Missing blame information for the following files:")

when i see generated sonar-project.properties i saw that problem is in projectBaseDir - it generates for each project in solution separately

i try to specify in command line like /d:sonar.projectBaseDir=... but no changes - it fully ignored

so my question is - can i use ms build runner and scm provider together with my repository structure?

UPDATE 1
i awas added verbose flag to my script..
now i run analysis with next command:

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner begin /n:projectName /k:projectKey /v:1.0 /d:sonar.scm.enabled=true /d:sonar.scm.provider=hg /d:sonar.projectBaseDir=d:\work\project1 /d:sonar.verbose=true
msbuild project1\src\solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
msbuild.sonarqube.runner end
```

in log i can see this messages:

```
[14:18:20] :     [Step 4/4] 14:18:20.403 DEBUG: Working directory: D:\work\project1\src\
[14:18:20] :     [Step 4/4] 14:18:20.416 DEBUG: Executing: hg blame -w -v --user --date --changeset API/AssignmentsController.cs
[14:18:20] :     [Step 4/4] 14:18:20.423 DEBUG: Executing: hg blame -w -v --user --date --changeset API/Commands/ImportCommand.cs
[14:18:20] :     [Step 4/4] 14:18:20.424 DEBUG: Executing: hg blame -w -v --user --date --changeset API/Dto/Assignment.cs
[14:18:20] :     [Step 4/4] 14:18:20.600 DEBUG: The mercurial blame command [hg blame -w -v --user --date --changeset API/AssignmentsController.cs] failed: abort: no repository found in 'D:\work\project1\src\' (.hg not found)!
[14:18:20] :     [Step 4/4]
```

and this is right - in folder d:\work\project1\src no .hg directory, because it's place in d:\work\project1

UPDATE2

ok, finally i find than i my mistake... on build machine folder .hg missed by some reasons...

Comment: Where are located your projects? The SonarQube root project baseDir is computed to be the common ancestor of all your projects referenced by your solution.

Comment: in each prj.* located csproj file foreach module, and i also found information about common ancestor, but in generated .properties file i can see that basedir setup to src\prj.infrastructure, src\prj.domain and so on... but event common ancestor is not answer for my case - becouse comon ancestor is src, and .hg dir located in parent of src...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the [SonarQube Mercurial Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-mercurial/blob/master/sonar-scm-mercurial-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/scm/mercurial/MercurialScmProvider.java#L42). It currently expects to find the .hg folder precisely in the basedir. Other plugins like SVN where [updated](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scm-svn/blob/master/sonar-scm-svn-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/scm/svn/SvnScmProvider.java#L43) to look recursively in parent folders.

We are no more actively developing the Mercurial plugin, but feel free to submit a pull request to fix the issue.

As a workaround, you can force the SCM using `/d:sonar.scm.provider=hg` in the begin step.

Comment: i already adding this argument to command, but i receive " Missing blame information for the following files:" messages...

Comment: Full logs of the analysis (with `/d:sonar.verbose=true`) would help